# How to create a div layout that looks like a tablet or a smartphone usiing html and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create a div that looks like a tablet or smartphone, using HTML and css or any other web related language. I also want to put some images inside that div. A good example is registration page of Instagram. The smartphone like animation they have on the left side and some animated images. I have searched allover the internet and I can't see one. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly are you looking?. you can use bootstrap for creating simple  nice tables and view.

Answer (score 5):

There are existing many good tutorials and templates in the internet. I will put some really good ones below.

- https://marvelapp.github.io/devices.css/
- http://callmenick.com/post/css-device-mockups
- http://designhooks.com/how-to-create-mobile-preview-tool-with-pure-css/

Note: I googled for **mobile phone in pure css**

Comment: Am checking those tutorials, I will get back to you @Axel. Thenks a lot.